# "Naked function cannot contain objects that would require unwinding..." for statically initialized variables

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I ran into a problem while using Visual Studio 15 to compile something. This code illustrates it:

```
const char* getx() { return "foo"; }

void __declspec(naked) nf()
{
    static const char* x = getx();
}
```

This fails with the following error: `Error C3068   'nf': a 'naked' function cannot contain objects that would require unwinding if a C++ exception occurred`. I don't really understand why this fails, though; static objects are not automatic and in terms of storage they behave more or less like globals and are initialized before the entry point is executed (to my understanding). If so, then what unwinding is this message referring to? There's nothing on the stack at this point, so nothing to unwind. Also, if I remove the function call, the `static` variable declaration is fine (so is the function call without the assignment, or assigning a constant value to the `x` variable, e.g. `static const char* x = 0;`).

**Am I missing something here?**

Comment: It's probably because static function variables aren't actually initialized before entry point. In most trivial cases it will be, but it's not required. In non-trivial cases (like initializing with a function call), the variable will be assigned at first call, with some non-trivial thread-safe code. Though I don't know where exactly it conflicts with 'naked', it makes sense that it does.

Comment: Try declaring getx() as a noexcept: "const char* getx() noexcept { return "foo"; }"

Comment: Static functions require an initialization synchronization guard; perhaps that's implemented in a non-trivial way.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Indeed, that solves the problem. It's curious because if I simply call `getx` in `nf` and discard the return value, the compiler never complains (`noexcept` or not). Thanks everyone for helpful suggestions/explanations. If someone posts an actual answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `noexcept` function attribute, introduced in C++11, formally declares that the function does not throw exceptions.

Even though no exceptions could possibly be thrown from getx(), the compiler will not automatically add the `noexcept` attribute, because this changes the function signature.

Consequently, when the compiler parses the `nf()` function, it sees a call to another function that could possibly throw an exception, which is, apparently, forbidden in your platform-specific "naked" function.

Explicitly declaring `getx` as `noexcept` explicitly declares that this function doesn't throw exception, so the compiler will know that this function call will not throw exception, and allow the "naked" function to compile.

Answer (score 1):

*Synthesizing from the comments:*

A static variable has to be initialized once, and only once. And this also has to be performed in a thread safe way.

A problem here is that if the initialization fails due to an exception, the variable is still uninitialized and the next time the function is called, another initialization will have to be performed.

This requires some (unspecified) implementation specific machinery to work correctly. Apparently it conflicts with making the function "naked".